# Relationship between unit endomorphisms of V and isomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am working through Curtis' Abstract Linear Algebra and I've having a bit of difficulty with one of the sections. It is proposed that:

$$\phi \in \mathit{End}(V) \text{ is a unit } \leftrightarrow \phi \text{ is an isomorphism}.$$

Where $\mathit{End}(V)$ is the set of all endomorphisms on some vector space, $V$. The reasoning for this proof is that as $\phi$ is a unit, $\exists \psi \in \mathit{End}(V)$ such that $\psi \phi = 1$ and $\phi \psi = 1$. I'm okay on this being the definition of a unit and commutativity, but I'm a bit lost on the notation. (Q1): I'm thinking of $\phi$ as being a linear operator, which would require at least one argument. Is it fair to say here that the lack of argument is shorthand for some arbitrary operator, $\psi$ and its inverse, $\psi$, such that the particular argument(s) is/are irrelevant?

The argument goes that the fact that $\phi \psi = 1$ implies $\phi$ is surjective and $\psi$ is injective, with the commutation implying the other way round, thus proving bijectivity and thus isomorphism. (Q2): This is perhaps a daft question, but does '1' mean the number one, or is it something more abstract? I'm having difficulty seeing how this demonstrates injection/surjection.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation being used indicates composition of functions. The result is a new function that can be applied to the vector space. The function takes an argument but it is not necessary to write it when we are not applying it to any particular vector.

1 denotes the identity map from $V$ to itself.

Suppose $fg=gf=1$. To prove $f$ is surjective, for any $v$ we want to find a $w$ such that $f(w)=v$. If we take $w=g(v)$, then $f(w)=f(g(v))=v$, so $f$ is surjective.

We also want to prove that if $f(v)=f(w)$, then $v=w$. In that case $v=g(f(v))=g(f(w))=w$, so $f$ is injective, hence bijective.

Comment: Thanks. How does the identity map imply bijectivity, though?

Comment: @AGPeddle please see my edit above.